# Redirect non-allowed IP's to specific page with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below code for example to allow only certain IP's to access the page..

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 123.45.67.89
allow from 123.45.

<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

..but how do I control the page the user is shown if they are not allowed? Like, I want to redirect them to a certain page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.45\.|19\.72\.48\.56)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^53\.81\.21\.94
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: Well it's actually only temporary and shouldn't be a 403 error; it's more so for a maintenance page redirect whilst allowing myself and others to still be able to access the site.

Comment: `deny from` does cause 403 status in browser.

Comment: `ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html` is pretty simple directive to use. Is there any objection using it?

Comment: Oh well since it was for the main page of the site (actually users shouldn't be able to access ANY page of the site) I didn't want to send a 403 code to google for example if they happened to crawl the site during this time.

Comment: so you want to send 200 with some custom page?

Comment: Awesome - what do I do if I wanna add extra IP's? Just add another line such as `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.678` ?

Comment: You can use regex OR: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.45\.|11\.22\.33\.44)`

Comment: Well these are just example IP's..... some IP's will be completley different so unfortunately something like that wouldn't work; is there a way to add each IP by itself?

Comment: I think you got confused some where. Example or no example it doesn't matter to this solution. You can place **ANY REAL IP** instead of `11.22.33.44`

Comment: Sorry, could you update your answer with a second IP so I can see what you mean better?

Comment: You can also add another condition like this: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^53\.81\.21\.94`